# db operations (Sql Common and JDBC client) executed in different event loops

Tags: vert.x

We are using rabbitmq in a verticle to receive messages. We wrapped Vert.x Common SQL interface as an separate jar file as `DBHelper`.

The `DBHelper` is initialized in rabbitmq verticle `start()`.

Every time a message arrives, it called `DBHelper` to update a column in our database. But when two messages come at very closed point, what we observed is that two db operations are performed in different event loops which results that the column in db doesn't have the latest value. For example, two messages ( one with a value, one with b value) came from rabbitmq (b value message came after a value message). The value of the column in DB is a instead of b.

Some code snippets:

rabbitmq verticle:

```
public final class MqVerticle extends AbstractVerticle {
    void start() {
        dbHelper = new DBHelper(vertx, db, username, password, 30);
    }

    //when message comes

    dbHelper.update(value);
}
```

DBHelper vertx:

```
public class DBHelper {

    private static JDBCClient jdbcClient;

    public static void init(Vertx vertx, String url, String user, String driver_class, String password, int max_pool_size) throws IOException {
        jdbcClient = JDBCClient.createShared(vertx, new JsonObject()
                .put("url", url)
                .put("driver_class", driver_class)
                .put("user", user)
                .put("password", password)
                .put("max_pool_size", max_pool_size));
    }

        public static void updateOne(String sql, JsonArray params, Consumer<Long> consumer) {
        jdbcClient.getConnection(ar -> {
            if(ar.failed()){
                throw new RuntimeException("connection failed:" + ar.cause().getLocalizedMessage());
            }else {
                SQLConnection connection = ar.result();
                connection.updateWithParams(sql, params, res -> {
                    if (res.failed()) {
                        throw new RuntimeException("sql failed:" + res.cause().getLocalizedMessage());
                    } else {
                        consumer.accept(res.result().getKeys().getLong(0));
                    }
                });
                connection.close();

            }
        });
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you want your `JDBCClient` to be `static`.

I assume you're doing it to reuse the pool.

Looking through the [docs](http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-jdbc-client/java/#_creating_a_the_client), they explain that:

> In most cases you will want to share a data source between different
>   client instances.
>
> E.g. you scale your application by deploying multiple instances of
>   your verticle and you want each verticle instance to share the same
>   datasource so you don’t end up with multiple pools
>
> You do this as follows:

```
JDBCClient client = JDBCClient.createShared(vertx, config);
```

There is no explanation or example of making the client static.

I would assume that you're creating multiple instances of the same `Verticle`. If you reduced it to 1 instance (so only one event loop) I would guess the problem goes away?

Comment: I modified the`JDCBClient` not to be static. The issue is still the same. Any other idea?

Comment: @Way Please post more code. This is too difficult from the partial code you've posted.